# Salesforce Integration License Profiles / Salesforce API Integration License agreement profiles not able to access controlled by parent custom objects

Tags: api, integration, profile

I want to convert a Salesforce license profile to Salesforce API Integration Profile.

- I have cloned the API profile and created a new profile with similar permissions with a permission set created using Salesforce API Integration Permission set License.
- I have a custom object whose sharing setting is controlled by parent because it has master details fields of Account and Opportunity objects in it.
- I have already assigned all the high-level permissions of parent objects in the permission set created earlier.

But, I’m still unable to access the custom object with this API Integration Profile.

Could you please help me if this is a bug or if I'm missing any security settings?

Comment: The permission set defines only CRUD on objects; you need to also look at your Sharing Settings that determine access to records

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's a Salesforce bug, it's a new feature after all, what to expect... But there is a workaround:

1- Create a Permission Set with a user license restricted to `Salesforce API Integration` license and assign it `Account` and `Opportunity` permissions

2- Create a Permission Set with **no** user license restrictions. Assign it the permissions of your custom objects which have a master detail to the Account and Opportunity.

3- Assign to your integration user, first the Permission Set created in #1, then the Permission Set created in #2.